# What implementation of average is the most accurate?

Tags: c++, algorithm, floating-accuracy

Given those two implementations of the average function:

```
float average(const vector<float>& seq)
{
  float sum = 0.0f;

  for (auto&& value : seq)
  {
    sum += value;
  }

  return sum / seq.size();
}
```

And:

```
float average(const vector<float>& seq)
{
  float avg = 0.0f;

  for (auto&& value : seq)
  {
    avg += value / seq.size();
  }

  return avg;
}
```

To illustrate my question, imagine we have a huge difference in the input data, like so:

```
1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1000000.0f
```

My guess is that in the first implementation, `sum` can grow "too much" and loose the least significant digits and be `1000000.0f` instead of `1000001.0f` at the end of the sum loop.

On the other hand, the second implementation seems *theorically* less efficient, due to the number of divisions to perform (I haven't profiled anything, this is a blind guess).

So, is one of these implementation preferable to the other ? Am I true that the first implementation is less accurate ?

Comment: Why don't you divide once in every `n` iterations, instead of in every iteration? You can compute the approximate value of `n` depending on the values in `seq`. Once you compute `n`, you can use it in an outer loop, and modify the code accordingly. There could be other variants of this approach.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm sure I understand properly what you mean. Do you have an example ?

Comment: See my answer to this question: [sum of small double numbers c++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10330002/1084416). It uses Kahan Summation as @James suggested.

Comment: @PeterWood: Thanks, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I'm not really sure why this was downvoted, but could you explain so that I have a chance for improvement ? (I never downvote, check my stats)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't count on the second being more accurate.  The
differences in the size of the elements are divided by the
length of the vector, but each division introduces some
additional imprecision.

If accuracy is a problem, the *first* step should be to use
`double`.  Even if the vector is `float`, for memory reasons,
the calculations within the function should be `double`.

Beyond that, for large numbers of elements, you should probably
use the [Kahan algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330002/sum-of-small-double-numbers-c), rather than just naïvely adding the
elements.  Although it adds a number of operations in the loop,
it keeps track of the error, and will result in significantly
more accuracy.

### EDIT:

Just for the fun of it, I wrote a small program which used the
following code to generate the vector:

```
std::vector<float> v;
v.push_back( 10000000.0f );
for ( int count = 10000000; count > 0; -- count ) {
    v.push_back( 0.1f );
}
```

The results of the average should be 1.0999999 (practically 
speaking, 1.1).  Using either of the algorithms in the original
posting, the results are 0.999999881: an error of 10%.  Just
changing `sum` to have type `double` in the first algorithm,
however, results in `1.0999999`, about as accurate as you can
get.  Using the Kahan algorithm (with float everywhere) gives
the same results.

Comment: Thank you very much. I took the liberty of adding a link to @PeterWood answer, that gives an implementation of the algorithm.

Comment: I especially like Peter Wood's implementation: defining a KahanAccumulator and using `std::accumulate`.  Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If your summation is not too big for type `float`, the first one might be more accurate because individual round-up errors produced by division may accumulate