# Is there any pythonic way to find average of specific tuple elements in array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tuples, average

I want to write this code as pythonic. My real array much bigger than this example.

( 5+10+20+3+2 ) / 5

> print(np.mean(array,key=lambda x:x[1]))
>   TypeError: mean() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'

```
array = [('a', 5) , ('b', 10), ('c', 20), ('d', 3), ('e', 2)]

sum = 0
for i in range(len(array)):
    sum = sum + array[i][1]

average = sum / len(array)
print(average)

import numpy as np
print(np.mean(array,key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

How can avoid this?
I want to use second example.

I'm using Python 3.7

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you are using Python 3.4 or above, you could use the [**`statistics`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) module:

```
from statistics import mean

average = mean(value[1] for value in array)
```

Or if you're using a version of Python older than 3.4:

```
average = sum(value[1] for value in array) / len(array)
```

These solutions both use a nice feature of Python called a generator expression. The loop

```
value[1] for value in array
```

creates a new sequence in a timely and memory efficient manner. See [PEP 289 -- Generator Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

If you're using Python 2, and you're summing integers, we will have integer division, which will truncate the result, e.g:

```
>>> 25 / 4
6

>>> 25 / float(4)
6.25
```

To ensure we don't have integer division we could set the starting value of `sum` to be the `float` value `0.0`. However, this also means we have to make the generator expression explicit with parentheses, otherwise it's a syntax error, and it's less pretty, as noted in the comments:

```
average = sum((value[1] for value in array), 0.0) / len(array)
```

It's probably best to use [**`fsum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum) from the [**`math`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module which will return a `float`:

```
from math import fsum

average = fsum(value[1] for value in array) / len(array)
```

Comment: I realised there are better ways to do the Python 2 code. `sum` takes an argument for the starting value. If you pass `0.0` to it, then the numerator will always be floating point, nothing to worry about. Also, there is a function in the [**`math`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html) module, [**`fsum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum).

Comment: I would say the `float` casting way is little bit more self-explanatory than passing a weird `0.0` value argument for the `sum`.

Comment: @ruohola I think using `fsum` is probably best for Python 2.

Comment: Can't you `from __future__ import division`?

Comment: @DanielSank yes, that's another option. Another advantage of using [**`fsum`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.fsum), if you're summing floats, is it keeps track of partial sums, which compensates for lack of precision in the floating point representation. So, if we stay using `fsum` we don't need to think about integer division at all, and are generally the better solution too. See my answer about [Kahan Summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330002/sum-of-small-double-numbers-c/10330857#10330857) in [tag:c++].

Comment: I don't understand "However, this also means we have to make the loop over the values in the array into a comprehension expression"... do you mean adding the explicit parentheses that converts the expression into a genexp? Because the previous variants of your solution all use genexps, just without the explicit parens because that isn't needed if there are no other arguments to the function.

Comment: @cs95 yes, that's what I meant. I've tried to improve the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you do want to use `numpy`, cast it to a `numpy.array` and select the axis you want using `numpy` indexing:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([('a', 5) , ('b', 10), ('c', 20), ('d', 3), ('e', 2)])
print(array[:,1].astype(float).mean())
# 8.0
```

The cast to a numeric type is needed because the original array contains both strings and numbers and is therefore of type `object`. In this case you could use `float` or `int`, it makes no difference.

Answer (score 3):

If you're open to more golf-like solutions, you can transpose your array with vanilla python, get a list of just the numbers, and calculate the mean with

```py
sum(zip(*array)[1])/len(array)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use:

```
print(sum(tup[1] for tup in array) / len(array))
```

Or for Python 2:

```
print(sum(tup[1] for tup in array) / float(len(array)))
```

Or little bit more concisely for Python 2:

```
from math import fsum

print(fsum(tup[1] for tup in array) / len(array))
```

Comment: As it's python 3, just use [**`statistics.mean`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean).

Answer (score 2):

With pure Python:

```
from operator import itemgetter

acc = 0
count = 0

for value in map(itemgetter(1), array):
    acc += value
    count += 1

mean = acc / count
```

An iterative approach can be preferable if your data cannot fit in memory as a `list` (since you said it was big). If it can, prefer a declarative approach:

```
data = [sub[1] for sub in array]
mean = sum(data) / len(data)
```

If you are open to using `numpy`, I find this cleaner:

```
a = np.array(array)

mean = a[:, 1].astype(int).mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `map` instead of list comprehension

```
sum(map(lambda x:int(x[1]), array)) / len(array)
```

or `functools.reduce` (if you use Python2.X just `reduce` not `functools.reduce`)

```
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda acc, y: acc + y[1], array, 0) / len(array)
```

Comment: first one gives this error :  'int' object is not callable

Comment: @ŞevvalKahraman if array is defined as shown in your question - the first one give 8.0 (tested & verified on same version). So either the array your using has a different value somewhere or you made a typo

Comment: `x[1]` is already an integer, why do you need to call `int()`?

Comment: Using a lambda is 30% slower than a generator comprehension. But if you prefer `map`, I recommend using `operator.itemgetter(1)` instead of the lambda.

Comment: Similarly, `functools.reduce` is 72% slower than a generator comprehension and `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`:

`np.mean(list(map(lambda x: x[1], array)))`

Answer (score 0):

Just find the average using sum and number of elements of the list.

```
array = [('a', 5) , ('b', 10), ('c', 20), ('d', 3), ('e', 2)]
avg = float(sum(value[1] for value in array)) / float(len(array))
print(avg)
#8.0
```